# Compiler Python, why are some wrong things overlooked?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, compilation, interpreter

I wrote a Python routine with a mistake in it: `false` instead of `False`. However, it was not discovered at compilation. The program had to run until this line to notify the wrongdoing.

Why is it so? What in the Python interpreter/compiler things make it work so?

Do you have some reference?

Comment: `false` is a valid variable name, not a syntax error.

Comment: For some extra fun in Python 2.7, do `True = 0; False = 1`. Hilarity ensues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to Python's dynamic nature, it is impossible to detect undefined names at compile time.  Only the syntax is checked; if the syntax is fine, the compiler generates the bytecode, and Python starts to execute the code.

In the given example, you will get a reference to a global name `false`.  Only when the bytecode interpreter tries to actually access this global name, you will get an error.

To illustrate, here is an example.  Do you think the following code executes fine?

```
globals()["snyfr".decode("rot13")] = 17
x = false
```

It actually does, since the first line dynamically generates a variable named `false`.

Answer (score 4):

You can think of this as the interpreter being 'lazy' about when to look up names: it does so as late as possible, because other bits of the program can fiddle around with its dictionary of known variables.

Consider the program

```
>>> def foo():
...     return false
... 
>>> def bar():
...     global false
...     false = False
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
NameError: global name 'false' is not defined
>>> bar()
>>> foo()
False
```

Notice that the first call to `foo` raised a `NameError`, because at the time that `foo` ran Python didn't know what `false` was. But `bar` then modified the global scope and inserted `false` as another name for `False`.

This sort of namespace-mucking allows for tremendous flexibility in how one writes programs. Of course, it also removes a lot of things that a more restrictive language could check for you.